# Problems with the comment.char argument

Tags: r, read.table

I'm downloading a data set from

```
url = "http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/misc/kings.dat"
```

Using `read.csv` works,

```
read.csv(url, comment.char="#")
```

but `read.table`

```
read.table(url, comment.char="#")
```

gives the error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 8 elements
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the first few lines of this file you get:

```
Age of Death of Successive Kings of England
#starting with William the Conqueror
#Source: McNeill, "Interactive Data Analysis"
60
43
67
```

When you use `read.table`, the default separator argument is `sep=""`, which the help file explains as:

```
sep: the field separator character.  Values on each line of the
     file are separated by this character.  If 'sep = ""' (the
     default for 'read.table') the separator is 'white space',
     that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage
     returns.
```

So the first line is treated as *eight* values. When `read.table` gets to the numeric values, we get the error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 8 elements
```

The `read.csv` function uses the comma as a separator and so the first line is just a single value.

Comment: think you ,`y<-read.table(url,comment.char="#",sep=",")` can work for me .

Comment: If you look at the code for `read.csv`, you will see that it's just calling `read.table`, but uses different defaults. One of which is the different separator.